# When will Hibernate lock table row?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am not quite understand table row locking mechanism.

If the method without `@Transactional`, I know it will lock when `.save()` method call.

```
public void test() {
    B b = a.findById(1);
    a.save(b);
}
```

When will lock the table row if the method use `@Transactional`?

```
 @Transactional
    public void test() {
        B b = a.findById(1);
        B b2 = a.findById(2);
        a.save(b);
        a.save(b2);
    }
```

Lock when enter the test method? or Lock when the first query? or Lock when `a.save(b)`?

Comment: have you read this https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pessimistic-locking ?

Comment: @Popeye It seem that not related to this(?). It just talk about how single query/action lock table row, but not when Transcational auto lock table row.

Answer (score 0):

When a row is locked depends on the database, connection isolation level and concrete queries that you use. Most databases implement a MVCC scheme so they can avoid locking rows unless explicitly requested. A DML statement (DELETE, UPDATE) on a row will always acquire an exclusive lock. Then there are various database vendor specific SELECT statement extensions that can be used to tell the database to lock certain rows. Hibernate uses that behind the scenes when you specify an explicit lock mode.

In your case, you do not specify a lock mode, so the lock will be acquired implicitly by the database when calling save, which will do a SQL UPDATE statement.